# Как обработать пакет данных (Java)

Tags: java

Устройство подключенное через переходник USART-USB отправляет на комп данные, программа на компе принимает пакет данных (при помощи библиотеки JSSC) в виде массива байт. Байты массива - это заранее определенные параметры, например "Состояние устройства", "Серийный номер" и т.п. соответственно нужна какая-то константная структура, реализующая таблицу соответствий - какой байт каким параметром является. Плюс нужна какая-то константная структура для интерпретации значения параметра к виду, подходящему для вывода в GUI, типа "FF" -> "IDLE", "FE" -> "SLEEP" и т.п. Причем таких состояний десятки и параметров десятки. Cейчас начал делать так:

```
public class Packet {
    public static String Partnum;
    public static String Version;
    public static String State;
    public static String LQI;
    public static String RSSI;
    public static String Freqest;
    public static String RXfifo;
    public static String VCO_VC_DAC;
    public static String WOR;

    public static void packetHandler(String[] arg) {
        Partnum = "0x"+arg[0];
        Version = "0x"+arg[1];

        // State
        if (arg[2].equals("0D")) {
            State = "RX";
        }

        else if (arg[2].equals("01")) {
            State = "IDLE";
        }

        else if (arg[2].equals("11")) {
            State = "RXFIFO_OVERFLOW";
        }

        else {
            State = arg[2];
        }

        LQI = arg[3];
        Freqest = arg[4];
        RSSI = arg[5];
        RXfifo = arg[6];
        VCO_VC_DAC = arg[7];
        WOR = arg[8]+" "+arg[9];
    }

}
```

Оно работает, но чувствую что так не правильно и не годится для обработки больших пакетов. Да и время на обработку, даже при количестве в несколько параметров, занимает просто огромное. 
Как корректно разобрать и интерпретировать содержание пакета инструментами Java? Может есть какие-то примеры? то что я нашел, оно интересно https://github.com/farrellf/TelemetryViewer/tree/master/Telemetry%20Viewer , но там пакет содержит просто значения для вывода и как таковой обработки и интерпретации не требуют.

Comment: Покажите пример массива байт, который приходит к вам, желательно сразу в виде hex

Comment: Например: 13 0d 89 0a 1c db ae 32 20 9a 50 ee 40 78 36 fd 12 49 32 f6 9e 7d 49 dc ad 4f 14 f2 . по сути с девайса отправляется содержание регистров, буферов и т.п. мне надо это как-то принять и обработать

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал что-то такое:

```
public class Packet {
   private int partNum;
   private int version;
   private String state;

private static boolean isRx(byte b) {
   return (b==0x0d)?true:false;
}

private static boolean isIdle(byte b) {
   return (b==0x01)?true:false;
}

private static boolean isOverflow(byte b) {
   return (b==0x11)?true:false;
}

public void parsePacketHandler(byte[] args) {
   this.partNum=args[0];
   this.version=args[1];
   if(isIdle(args[2))
     this.state="idle";
   else if(isRx(args[2]))
     this.state="rx";
   else if(isOverflow(args[2]))
     this.state="overflow"
   else
     this.state=""+args[2];
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Меня как раз смущает, что при подобном подходе все норм, если параметров мало и вариантов значений у них мало, а когда речь идет о десятках параметров и десятках значений, то это перерастает в какие-то длинные листинги нечитаемого кода. Ну и время исполнения смущает, можно ли распараллелить обработку в несколько потоков при такой идеологии. Думаю может коллекции применить, но они заточены под динамическое изменение содержимого, а мне по-сути надо нечто вроде таблицы констант.

Comment: Под каждый параметр свой класс делать что ли.. или подкласс

Comment: В вашем коде, разбор данных вы делали через `String`, что нелогично. Я же сделал, парсинг байтов, что намного эффективнее. К сожалению, когда вы разбираете массив битов/байтов длинного малопонятного листинга все равно не избежать

Comment: Как оказалось byte использовать в Java категорически неудобно, поскольку оно вмещает только числа от -128 до 127, т.е. например 0xFE просто не влезает. Какой-то нетрадиционно-ориентированный байт. Приходится использовать Int.

Comment: @MikhailKrechko вы сами то хоть поняли что написали? `0xFE=-2` - в Java нотации и чему это мешает то?

Comment: static byte[] packet = {0xFE, 0x01}; так вот "0xFE" подчеркивается как ошибка "cannot convert from int to byte"